# Best way to setup a network in a docker-compose.yml file within Visual Studio?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

What I am trying to do is create web application stack that resembles something like the following:

http://172.68.54.44/web
http://172.68.54.44/api

So that in my two projects I can reference them by "/api" or "/web".

Below is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: web
    build:
      context: ./Web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - api

  api:
    image: api
    build:
      context: ./API
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

I have tried to define my own network and when I try to compile this within Visual Studio 2017 I get an error. Maybe I am doing this wrong but my understanding is that each service will spawn off its own container. Both of these containers is on a host image. Should I set the image to be the same on both services?

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Compose version 2+ definitions create a docker network automatically but I think you are asking a different question. You probably need something in front of your web apps like nginx, traefix or haproxy to listen for requests and proxy them to the appropriate back end service.

Comment: [example haproxy config](https://serverfault.com/questions/127491/haproxy-forward-to-a-different-web-server-based-on-uri)

Comment: Thanks Matt for your response. I think I am missing something. This project is within Visual Studio 2017. I have created two web applications, one is a .net core web application and the other is .net core web api application. What I am trying to understand is what is the best way to create the docker-compose.yml file that will search each application within their own folder (/web or /api) on the same IP Address (172.68.54.44).

Comment: Docker itself doesn't provide that functionality. One way is to have a third container that runs some kind of web proxy. The 3rd container listens for all web requests, then forwards requests for the  `/web` path onto the `web` container, and requests for `/api` to the `api` container.

Comment: Are you are using windows native containers? Your options are probably limited if you are.

Answer (score 0):

Docker itself doesn't provide the functionality to route requests to container based on URL information (layer 7).

One way to merge the apps is to have a third container that runs some kind of web proxy. The 3rd container listens for all web requests, then forwards requests for the `/web` path onto the `web` container, and requests for `/api` to the `api` container.

[Traefik](https://traefik.io/), [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/), Apache http, Nginx, Varnish, Squid all support this type of request routing, each with it's own additional features. I'm not sure if any are available for native Windows containers.

```
version: '3'

services:
  proxy:
    image: haproxy
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'

  web:
    image: web
    build:
      context: ./Web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - api

  api:
    image: api
    build:
      context: ./API
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

HAProxy config:

```
frontend http-in
    bind :80
    acl its_an_api_request path_beg /api
    acl its_a_web_request path_beg /web
    use_backend api_server if its_an_api_request
    use_backend web_server if its_a_web_request
    default_backend web_server

backend api_server
    server api_1 api:80

backend web_server
    server web_1 web:80
```

Comment: Thank you Matt for your response. I have tried Traefik and HAProxy within Visual Studio 2017, both of which give me an error when I try to configure them. Do you know of any proxy service that runs properly within Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: And yes I am running Docker for Windows.

Comment: [When you add Docker support to your project, you can choose either Windows or Linux containers. (The Docker host must be running the same container type. If you need change the container type in the running Docker instance, right-click the Docker icon in the System Tray, and choose Switch to Windows containers or Switch to Linux containers.)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/visual-studio-tools-for-docker).  Traefik and HAProxy will run if you use Linux containers and I guess that means only .Net core.  I'm not sure what Windows container images serve the same purpose.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Is there a way to link the two .NET Core apps together within Window Containers? Or do I have to use Linux Containers only?

Comment: Maybe not with "/web" or "/app" but maybe through environment variables that can be populated with the apps URL? For instance, if the WEB service could have an Environment Variable created within docker-compose.yml that is populated with the API service URL.

Comment: I read about "links" in the docker-compose.yml file. Could this work for my situation?
[code]
    version: '3'
    
    services:
      web:
        image: web
        build:
          context: ./Web
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        links:
          - api:service
    
      api:
        image: api
        build:
          context: ./API
          dockerfile: Dockerfile

Comment: My apologies, I just read that "links" have been deprecated. Would "environment" work instead?

Comment: I have uploaded my sample project to GitHub at [https://github.com/sroye98/ContainerSolutions](https://github.com/sroye98/ContainerSolutions). I still can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Docker has been updated to use Linux Containers. I've created a folder to hold HAProxy configuration file as well as Dockerfile for HAProxy. I've also updated docker-compose.yml. When you get a chance can you have a look and let me know what I am doing wrong?